# Swift: Switch statement fallthrough behavior

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Currently I have this:

```
let somePoint = (1, 0)

switch somePoint {
case (0,0):
    print("origin") // does not print
    fallthrough
case (_, 0):
    print("y-axis") // prints y-axis. this makes sense
    fallthrough
case(0, _):
    print("x-axis") // prints x-axis (because of fallthrough? this should not print)
    fallthrough
case(-2...2, -2...2):
    print("in 5x5 box about the origin") // this prints and makes sense
default:
    print("somewhere else") // does not print
}
```

My goal with this switch statement is to have each case print if it is true and NOT to have only the first case that is matched print. I thought I could do this with the fallthrough statement. However, this has made me question how it works. Why does fallthrough automatically print the next case in line even if the case does not match? How could I go about making this switch statement work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Fallthrough` falls through to the next case, not to the next matching case. The concept is inherited from C `switch` statements, where each `case` may be thought of as a `goto` destination label, and the `switch` statement brings execution to the first matching one.

In C, the `switch` statement only dictates where execution *starts* inside the block. For added convenience, you *may* use the `break` statement to skip the rest of the `switch` body, but nothing forces you to; and if you don't, execution continues normally, like the `case`s weren't there. For instance:

```
switch (countdown)
{
    case 3: puts("3...");
    case 2: puts("2...");
    case 1: puts("1...");
    case 0: puts("0!");
}
```

With no `break` anywhere, if `countdown` is 3, then you get the whole thing (even though `countdown` is obviously 3, and not 2, 1 or 0).

When execution goes from a case to another instead of exiting the `switch` scope (for instance, with a `break` statement), you get "fall through" (which is what the Swift `fallthrough` keyword does).

This is relevant in C as you are allowed to use arbitrarily complex structures inside `switch` statements, overlapping cases if you want. Here is a legal C program:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0:
        if (y == 3)
        {
    case 1:
            puts("hello");
        }
        else
        {
            puts("world");
        }

    case 2:
        puts("!");
}
```

This kind of use is however extremely uncommon and often hard to follow (quick! can the else branch be executed if `x == 1`?). I haven't tested, but I would be very surprised if you could do something similar with Swift.

In general, in C, fall through is considered poor style since it is often hard to tell if the fall through is voluntary or due to a missing `break` statement. Swift solves this with the `fallthrough` statement, which makes it explicit that you want execution to continue to the next case inside the `switch` statement rather than exit the `switch` scope.

In your case, you cannot use fallthrough to get what you want, because fallthrough is only useful when the execution sequence you need is linear. You need to skip over invalid blocks of code, so you need to use an `if-else` sequence instead of a `switch` statement.

Comment: in C# it's solved by using `goto case X`, easy to read without the need of a new keyword

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, that's possible because of the limited nature of C# (and C/C++/etc) cases (relative to Swift) and not really what the OP wants. They want to go to another case *and start searching for another match.* C# goto case doesn't re-evaluate because the selection criteria are not dynamic. In other words, you already have to know where you're going.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to fall through to other *matching* cases rather than the next (as `fallthrough` does), `switch` is not the right tool for the job.

Instead, you should use a series of `if` statements, something like:

```
Bool gotOne = false;
if (somePoint.0 == 0 && somepoint.1 == 0) {
    print("origin")
    gotOne = true;
}
if (somepoint.1 == 0) {
    print("y-axis")
    gotOne = true;
}
if (somepoint.0 == 0) {
    print("x-axis")
    gotOne = true;
}
:
if (! gotOne) {
    print("somewhere else")
}
```