# Swift sample code using switch, case and fallthrough

Tags: swift

In the following code sample, I don't understand why "Value 7" gets printed instead of "Default". Case 7, i.e. x=7 is not met because x=6, so why does "Value 7" get printed instead of being skipped and the execution falling through to default?

```
let x = 6
 
switch x {
     
case 0...5:
    println("0 through 5")
     
case 6:
    fallthrough
     
case 7:
    println("Value 7")
     
default:
    println("Default")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Switch statement fallthrough behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343690/swift-switch-statement-fallthrough-behavior)

Comment: Also see the `fallthrough` [section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID140) – "*The `fallthrough` keyword does not check the case conditions for the `switch` case that it causes execution to fall into. The `fallthrough` keyword simply causes code execution to move directly to the statements inside the next case (or `default` case) block, as in C’s standard `switch` statement behavior.*"

Comment: Thank you, Hamish.

Answer (score 5):

When `x` = 6 the switch statements finds the `case` for 6 then it 'falls through' to the *next* case *not* the default one. If you want the `case` for 6 to execute the code under `default` remove that `case` as it does nothing. If you plan to add some code to the `case` for 6 then make it the last one before `default` so it falls through to the place you want.